# vscode( vscode-ruby + rubocop ) how to auto correct on save?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

### Environments

- vscode Version 1.19.1 (1.19.1)
- rubocop (0.52.1)
- Darwin mbp 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Wed Oct  4 00:17:00 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.71.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
- ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-darwin16]

followed https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby#linters and installed all gems and edited the settings.json like this.

```js
{

  "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/Users/ac/.rbenv/shims/",
  "ruby.rubocop.onSave": true,
  "ruby.lint": {
    "ruby": {
      "unicode": true //Runs ruby -wc -Ku
    },
    "reek": true,
    "rubocop": {
      "lint": true,
      "rails": true
    },
    "fasterer": true,
    "debride": {
      "rails": true //Add some rails call conversions.
    },
    "ruby-lint": true
  },
  "ruby.locate": {
    "include": "**/*.rb",
    "exclude": "{**/@(test|spec|tmp|.*),**/@(test|spec|tmp|.*)/**,**/*_spec.rb}"
  }

}
```

On vscode, code highlighting is working fine.
*just to note, you see the extensions installed, and warnings in the problem tab.

[image: rubocop is working ok]

### Question

I was under the inpression that `vscode-ruby` and `rubocop` would auto-correct indentations and cop rules on **file save**, but apparently it doesn't.
If I want it to format my code like `prettier`, how should I set this up?

Comment: even I am looking for the same in vs code.

Comment: your config helped, too. i want to buy you a beer. months wrangling with this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/issues/49#issuecomment-417617844) on the vscode-ruby-rubocop GitHub, you can use the following settings:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000,
    "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "path/where/rubocop/is/located",
    "ruby.format": "rubocop",
}
```

Just applied them to my user settings on my local box and it appears to work. VS Code was throwing an error for my `ruby.rubocop.executePath` setting saying it wasn't executable, and removing the line appears to not cause that error to show, and still formats my code accordingly. Setting a lower timeout (I tried 2500) also seems to break auto format on saving, so I'd suggest leaving it at 5000.

Comment: For my environment setting `"editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000` did the trick, I had it set to 1500 and it wasn't working. Also `"ruby.rubocop.executePath"` seems to be unrecognised, perhaps it's since been removed?

Comment: This is the magic setting that fixes everything and should be the default when you install Visual Studio: `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Comment: `"editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000` has solved my problem too. cheers

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't work with the `-A` argument. You still need to manually run the Rubocop CLI with `-A`.

Comment: @dimiguel Not sure if there's a setting to enable it by default, but there's a command palate option of "Rubocop: autocorrect by rubocop" that may be of use here?

https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop#features

Answer (score 10):

I've tried all the options other people shared and it fixed linking for me (so I would get warnings when my code wasn't formatted correctly) but it didn't fix indentation or other formatting on save.

What seemed to work for me is adding a default formatter option. If you look at the bottom right corner in vscode you should see a notification icon which might throw in a few warnings that can help with your config. For me it was adding:

```
"[ruby]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "misogi.ruby-rubocop"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Now, it's enough just adding these lines:

```json
{
  "ruby.rubocop.onSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for a while and none of the other solutions worked for me.
According to a [github comment](https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/issues/113#issuecomment-769648251), what solved was:

> I Replace `bin` in the PATH with `wrappers` and solved the issue:
> vscode setting:
> `ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/`

**Note:** Another useful thing you could check if none of the above worked for you is to check your home folder for a `.rubocop.yml` file (`~/.rubocop.yml`) and delete it so you only have your project's `.rubocop.yml` working on.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure autocorrection works with ruby-rubocop add below settings
make sure  "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "path/where/rubocop/is/located", is set to default 
 "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "",

Add the following to your json file in vscode

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000,
"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "",
"ruby.format": "rubocop",
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the extension [ruby-rubocop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misogi.ruby-rubocop), last updated in Dec 2021. It seems it's still using the auto-correct command `--autocorrect` while Rubocop now uses `--auto-correct`. I switched to another extension, [ruby-rubocop-revived](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LoranKloeze.ruby-rubocop-revived), which fixed my auto-correct issue.

It also introduces the `useServer` option that speeds up the execution.

Here are the settings I used:

```js
# .vscode/settings.json

  "ruby.format": "rubocop",
  "ruby.rubocop.onSave": true,
  "ruby.rubocop.useServer": true,
  "[ruby]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rebornix.ruby"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

## May 2023 update:

The extension referred in the question under `vscode-ruby` (which is in fact `rebornix.Ruby`) is [deprecated](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby#deprecated) and no longer maintained.

A modern way is to use [Ruby LSP extension from Shopify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.ruby-lsp) (`Shopify.ruby-lsp`) and add `"editor.formatOnSave": true`. See [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76295215/2987689) on setting up the autocorrection.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is now thankfully outdated

--
Unfortunately this cannot be done with the current rubocop extension. The primary use case is to lint your ruby and show visual cues in the IDE.

It is currently an open issue/feature request on github. View this issue to see progress until it is resolved.

https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/issues/49

Comment: This can be done with the rubocop extension and the VS Code `"editor.formatOnSave": true` setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the answer @Artur INTECH
also need to add in settings.json option `"rubyLsp.formatter": "rubocop"`

for example my settings.json looks like that:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "ruby.useLanguageServer": true,
    "ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
    "[ruby]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Shopify.ruby-lsp",
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
        "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
        "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            120
        ],
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000000,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "rubyLsp.formatter": "rubocop",
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Spinel",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
}
```